# c++ How to istream struct contains vector

Tags: c++

How to istream struct that contains vector of integer as member, I tried the following code but it failed to read the file

```
struct Ss{
    std::vector<int> a;
    double b;
    double c;    };

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream &is, Ss &d)
{
    int x;
    while (is >> x)  
        d.a.push_back(x);
    is >> d.b;
    is >> d.c;
    return is;
}
std::vector <std::vector<Ss >> Aarr;

void scanData()
{
    ifstream in;
    in.open(FileInp);
    std::string line;


    while (std::getline(in, line))
    {
        std::stringstream V(line);
        Ss S1;
        std::vector<Ss > inner;
        while (V >> S1)
            inner.push_back(std::move(S1));
        Aarr.push_back(std::move(inner));

    }
}
```

I did search for similar problems but i could not find one.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "it failed to read the file"?

Comment: You may need to call `is.clear()` after `is >> x` evaluates to false.

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin: Yeah, except by then it's already consumed the integer part of the first double and put it on the vector.

Comment: @FredLarson You are quite right.

Comment: Show a sample input file or its format.

Answer (score 1):

The immediate problem here is that the same condition that terminates your `while` loop prevents the successive reads from working. The stream is in an error state. So your `double` values are never read.

Actually, the integer part of the first `double` is read as an integer, leaving the fractional part in the stream. You can't recover from this.

One way to solve this might be to read in your values as strings, converting them to integers using `stoi` and putting them in the vector. But before you do the integer conversion, check for a decimal point in the string. If it contains one, break out of the loop. Convert the double values using `stod`.